# PickList Azure Devops Custom Task

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-build-task, picklist

How can I populate a pickLists in Azure Devops Tasks with a json file?

I have this json file:

```
[
    {"Item1":"Item1"},
    {"Item2":"Item2"},
    {"Item3":"Item3"},
    {"Itemn":"Itemn"}
]
```

I need that the pickList recibe this file as a parameter and show this options, somethink like this...

```
{
            "name": "businessprocess",
            "type": "pickList",
            "label": "Business",
            "defaultValue": "",
            "required": true,
            "helpMarkDown": "Select One"
            "options": path to jsonFile....
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid we don't have such out-of-box way to populate the pickLists with another json file.

You can check [tasks.json schema](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-task-lib/blob/7b32ca7fb2d2f6fe966dd2b413b6f38a1a6eeebf/tasks.schema.json#L224), the `options` element is designed to be an `object` type. And as I know json objects should be written in `key/value` pairs with format `{ "key1":"xx", "key2":xx, "key3":xx}`. So you can't pass the path of jsonFile as property of `options` element, that's not expected key-value pairs of `options`.

Instead I think you should write the key-value pairs directly in tasks.json file, just like what our [official tasks](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/6ca9a8995f22ed21f2ea6716673bb207dcac1c8f/Tasks/DotNetCoreCLIV2/task.json#L69) do:

```
            "options": {
                "build": "build",
                "push": "nuget push",
                "pack": "pack",
                "publish": "publish",
                "restore": "restore",
                "run": "run",
                "test": "test",
                "custom": "custom"
            }
```